# add new record element by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table insite form where I want to be able to duplicate a group of fields as many times as I want. And I also want to have field id, name, and label's for attributes of those new group of fields increase by 1. I've tried this so far with jQuery, and got it to at least duplicate the group of fields, but remove doesn't work. And I'm not sure how to do +1 for each of those 3 attributes. I appreciate any help I can get.

```
    <tr>
        <td>name<span class="description"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="type_1" id="type_11" class="regular-text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>pic<span class="description"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="logo_1" id="logo_1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <div class="formRowRepeatingSection"><a href="#" class="addPro">Add New</a>
    </div>
<div class="repeatingSection"></div>
```

JS - Jquery

```
$(function(){
$('#addPro').click(function() {


    $('#repeatingSection').append('<tr><td>name<span class="description"></span></td><td><input type="text" name="pro_1'+i+'[]" id="pro_1'+i+'[] class="regular-text" /></td></tr><tr><td>pic<span class="description"></span></td><td><input type="file" name="pro_pic_1'+i+'[]" id="pro_pic_1'+i+'[]" /></td></tr>');



}); 
});
```

i need repate in '#repeatingSection' this code html when click '#addPro'

edit:-

```
$(function(){
$('#addPro').click(function() {

    $('#repeatingSection').append('<tr><td>name<span class="description"></span></td><td><input type="text" name="pro_1'+i+'[]" id="pro_1'+i+'[]" class="regular-text" /></td></tr><tr><td>pic<span class="description"></span></td><td><input type="file" name="pro_pic_1'+i+'[]" id="pro_pic_1'+i+'[]" /></td></tr>');



}); 
});
```

i will edit now .... but i need when click in `#addPro` insert new row

Comment: "but remove doesn't work."?

Comment: WHat do you expect to get from `$(this).val()` ? In that code the `this` is a `<a>` element

Comment: @Sergio sorry i will edit my code

Comment: In your HTML you define "addPro" class, but in jQuery your selector is looking for "addPro" id. Use $(".addPro") or <a href="#" id="addPro"...>

Comment: You missed a `"` clising the ID here `id="pro_1'+i+'[] class="regular-text"`

Comment: @Sergio i will edit my code

Comment: Is it still not working? Add `var i = 0;` outside the click function and `i++;` inside it. Now it should be working. Try that.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/)? It would be much easier to spot the error in your code.

Comment: @Sergio can you edit in my code

Comment: @k300, don't edit your question. I posted an answer and a demo. It's better if your question is not changed so your problem is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>name<span class="description"></span>

        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="type_1" id="type_11" class="regular-text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>pic<span class="description"></span>

        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="logo_1" id="logo_1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="formRowRepeatingSection"><a href="#" id="addPro">Add New</a>

</div>
<div id="repeatingSection"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $('#addPro').click(function () {
        console.log(i);
        i++;
        $('#repeatingSection').append('<tr><td>name<span class="description"></span></td><td><input type="text" name="pro_1' + i + '[]" id="pro_1' + i + '[]" class="regular-text" /></td></tr><tr><td>pic<span class="description"></span></td><td><input type="file" name="pro_pic_1' + i + '[]" id="pro_pic_1' + i + '[]" /></td></tr>');
    });
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MsRqD/)

What I changed:

- replaced in html: class to ID in the `<a>` element and in the div to append to `#repeatingSection`
- added `"` closing the ID here `id="pro_1'+i+'[] class="regular-text"`
- added `var i = 0;` outside the click function and `i++;` inside it.
- I added also opening and closing tags for `<table>`,maybe you have them somewhere else in the code you didn't posted. I added just to have correct html markup.